# How is Spider-Man's suit dodging Dr. Strange in this scene?

Tags: spider-man, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021), I didn't understand how Spider-Man's suit is dodging Dr. Strange in this scene if Peter Parker separated from his suit:
[image: animated GIF of scene]

How is Spider-Man's suit dodging Dr. Strange in this scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Peter's suit dodging, but rather his body. From the transcript [here:](https://movies.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man:_No_Way_Home/Transcript)

> Peter Parker: Oh, my God. I'm dead.
>
> Stephen Strange: You're not dead. You've just been separated from your
> physical form.
>
> Peter Parker: My physical... What?!
>
> [When Strange reaches out to retrieve the box from Peter's grip, the
> arm suddenly moves upwards]
>
> Stephen Strange: [confused] How are you doing that?

Although it is not explicitly mentioned in the film, his Spider-Sense helps him dodge attacks unconsciously, without even needing to think about it, meaning that even when Doctor Strange knocks his soul out of his body, his reflexes still respond to his desires.